# Console application with Topshelf throws an exception when running as a service

Tags: topshelf

I've developed a Console Application that connects to RabbitMQ then process some messages. I'm using Topshelf to allow the execution as a service without (on the paper) issues, but when I run it as a service I got the following exception

> Application: XXX.exe Framework
>   Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an
>   unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
>   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(Boolean)
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(System.Collections.Generic.IList`1)
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build() at
>   XXX.Program.Main(System.String[])

Now I think it's somehow missing the configuration file or some dll but I've all the files a folder on c:\services\myservice. If I run the exe from command prompt it works flawlessly.

I've also tried to set the identity to network service / admin user and similar... with no luck. I'm using TopShelf 4.0.4

Any suggestion?
Thanks

## SOLUTION

It was a fault of mine...

I had to use

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location))
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.{environmentName}.json",true,true);
```

instead of

```
 var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder() 
 .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()) //(which is the default code present on MS site)
 .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
 .AddJsonFile("appsettings.{environmentName}.json",true,true);
```

Comment: your `update` solved my problem.   Perhaps you should answer your own question, and I can upvote that.

Comment: thanks so much, saved me what would have been probably hours of head scratching after I just went to prod with my new service!

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @bozoJoe here's the answer to my question, for upvote

SOLUTION
It was a fault of mine...

I had to use

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location))
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.{environmentName}.json",true,true);
```

instead of

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder() 
.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()) //(which is the default code present on MS site)
.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
.AddJsonFile("appsettings.{environmentName}.json",true,true);
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH. I was instantly getting the error "The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion" when starting the service, but this was the solution that worked for me.